# VB6 - Which event is invoked by the X button?

Tags: vb6

I would like to activate a piece of code in my MDI form when the red X button at the upper right is clicked (I don't know what it is officially called) so that the program closes down nicely.

What method in the Form is invoked when that happens?

Comment: not that this answers your question, but did you know that VB6 was introduced in 1998 ?  :)

Comment: @Cheeso, and I'm only just learning it. Nothing like being up with the latest trends, is there?

Comment: Since I have read the 1998 comment after answering the question, I am feeling very old now :(

Comment: Hey Brian - is this for work?  Cause if not, then maybe you should be learning Visual Basic Express (with VB.NET), which is a better tool than the commercial VB6 tool.  VB6 (the tool) is out of support now, from Microsoft, unless you have a special support contract. Very few do.  And there are "VB.NET For Dummies" books, makes it easy to learn.  No, I did not just call you a dummy.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @Cheeso, I never suspected you were, and yes, it is for work. Whether that is any mitigation I'm not sure...

Comment: @cheeso In the interests of accuracy: the VB6 runtime is still fully supported by Microsoft. But, yes, Brian should strongly consider using VB.Net.

Comment: Indeed, the VB6 runtime is considered a protected and fully supported part of Windows these days.  However at the same time this is very late to be learning VB6 from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Form_QueryUnload` is called. Since you have indicated an MDI application, the exact event invoked is

`Private Sub MDIForm_QueryUnload(cancel As Integer, unloadmode As Integer)`

where if you set `cancel` to a non-zero value inside this function, it stops the application from exiting. In other words, `QueryUnload` is a way to query if the form should unload or not. The second argument, `unloadmode` gives you the information how this unloading was triggered.

[More help on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445536%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you. That's what I was looking for. Please excuse the baby-talk in my questions; I'm an X/Motif man really and the jargon is all different. Find what you want isn't easy if you don't know what anything is called.

Answer (score 5):

[Using the Unload and QueryUnload Events in an MDI Application](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson6/p8.html)

> When you attempt to unload the main
>   MDI form in an MDI application, VB
>   unloads all the open Child forms
>   first. This means that the various
>   Unload and QueryUnload events have a
>   special timing relationship in an MDI
>   application. When there is an attempt
>   to unload the main MDI form, the order
>   of the Unload and QueryUnload events
>   is as follows:
>
> 1.The MDI form's `QueryUnload` event 
>      2.The `QueryUnload` event of each open Child form
>      3. The `Unload` event of each Child form
>      4. The `Unload` event of the MDI form
>
> If Cancel is set to True within any of
>   these event procedures, the entire
>   unloading process stops. If unloading
>   is halted during any of the
>   QueryUnload event procedures, then
>   none of the Unload events is
>   triggered, and no form is unloaded. If
>   unloading is halted during any of the
>   Unload event procedures, then only
>   forms whose Unload events happened
>   before the one where the Cancel
>   occurred will unload.

Comment: thank you. That may well have saved me a good deal of trouble in the next few hours.

Comment: it also appears to be invoking the Form_Load for each of them. Would you expect that or is something else wrong?

Comment: `Form_Load` for child windows on exit? I doubt. Anyway, add some code like `MsgBox ` in `Form_Load` and put a breakpoint (`F9` inserts a breakpoint). If the debugger stops on your breakpoint press `Ctrl-L` and inspect your call stack.

Comment: sorry for the extra trouble. It just occurred to me that after running the tidy close code, I can then terminate the program with extreme prejudice and thus don't care what it wishes to do. Thanks again for your help.